# Where am I missing an argument?

Tags: python, whoosh

I'm about to go blind starring at this problem, so I have to ask:

I have 1 clue: rearranging the code, makes the error message different:

I get the error: min_analyzer = SpaceSeparatedTokenizer() | LowercaseFilter() | mitt_filter()
TypeError: **_*call*_**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

From this code:

```
import sqlite3
from whoosh.fields import Schema, TEXT, ID
from whoosh.index import create_in
from whoosh.analysis import SpaceSeparatedTokenizer
from whoosh.analysis import StopFilter
from whoosh.analysis import LowercaseFilter

mitt_filter = StopFilter(stoplist=frozenset(['and', 'is', 'it', 'an', 'as', 'at', 'have',     'in', 'yet', 'if', 'from', 'for', 'when', 'by', 'to', 'you', 'be', 'we', 'that', 'may', 'not', 'with', 'a', 'on', 'your', 'this', 'of', 'us', 'will', 'can', 'the', 'or', 'are', u'og', u'i', u'-', u'\\xa0', u'for', u'av', u'til', u'p\\xe5', u'the', u'and', u'as', u'med', u'er', u'en', u'of', u'to', u'har', u'Vi', u'kontakt', u'som', u'\\xe5', u'v\\xe5re', u'vi', u'in', u'oss', u'a', u'det', u'at', u'is', u'\\u2013', u'/', u'\\xbb', u'kan', u'by', u'skal', 'fra', u'ut', u'with', u'be', u'v\\xe5rt', u'mer', u'du', u'\\xa9', u'us', u'on', u'hopp', u'ogs\\xe5', u'Hopp']), minsize=2, maxsize=None, renumber=False)

min_analyzer = SpaceSeparatedTokenizer() | LowercaseFilter() | mitt_filter()

schema = Schema(Hoveddomene=ID, innhold=TEXT (stored=True,     analyzer=min_analyzer(removestops=False, positions=True)), webadresse=ID)

ix = create_in('/Users/Sverdrup/virtualenv-1.6.1/whoosh/whoosh directory/', schema)
```

If I rearrange the code like so:

```
import sqlite3

from whoosh.fields import Schema, TEXT, ID
from whoosh.index import create_in
from whoosh.analysis import SpaceSeparatedTokenizer
from whoosh.analysis import StopFilter
from whoosh.analysis import LowercaseFilter

min_analyzer = SpaceSeparatedTokenizer() | LowercaseFilter() | StopFilter(stoplist=frozenset(['and', 'is', 'it', 'an', 'as', 'at', 'have', 'in', 'yet', 'if', 'from', 'for', 'when', 'by', 'to', 'you', 'be', 'we', 'that', 'may', 'not', 'with', 'a', 'on', 'your', 'this', 'of', 'us', 'will', 'can', 'the', 'or', 'are', u'og', u'i', u'-', u'\\xa0', u'for', u'av', u'til', u'p\\xe5', u'the', u'and', u'as', u'med', u'er', u'en', u'of', u'to', u'har', u'Vi', u'kontakt', u'som', u'\\xe5', u'v\\xe5re', u'vi', u'in', u'oss', u'a', u'det', u'at', u'is', u'\\u2013', u'/', u'\\xbb', u'kan', u'by', u'skal', 'fra', u'ut', u'with', u'be', u'v\\xe5rt', u'mer', u'du', u'\\xa9', u'us', u'on', u'hopp', u'ogs\\xe5', u'Hopp']), minsize=2, maxsize=None, renumber=False)

schema = Schema(Hoveddomene=ID, innhold=TEXT (stored=True, analyzer=min_analyzer(removestops=False, positions=True)), webadresse=ID)

ix = create_in('/Users/Sverdrup/virtualenv-1.6.1/whoosh/whoosh directory/', schema)
```

This clue leads me to believe that it's the declaration of the stopFilter function that's wrong, but I can't see that it is?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I get the following error: schema = Schema(Hoveddomene=ID, innhold=TEXT (stored=True, analyzer=min_analyzer(removestops=False, positions=True)), webadresse=ID)
TypeError: **_*call*_**() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: To debug, try inserting newlines in between arguments and/or after binary operators. That might give you more precise information about the location of your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want `mitt_filter`, otherwise you are executing `__call__` on the instantiated object, which is different from your second sample.

```
min_analyzer = SpaceSeparatedTokenizer() | LowercaseFilter() | mitt_filter
```

As your second sample is more correct, that error is saying that you probably shouldn't be passing arguments to `min_analyzer` when sending it to the `Schema` constructor. I'm basically saying that `analyzer=min_analyzer` is probably more correct, and the `removestops` and `positions` arguments should be supplied elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you o'holy Savior. Thy name Michael Merickel shall echo through the ages and into all eternity in the land of Rookie!

Answer (score 1):

Your `analyzer` argument to `Schem`a constructor is incorrect.  analyzer must be a function or a class with the `__call__` method, hence your error about `call`.

http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/analysis.html

Comment: I'm guessing TJD's answer says the same as Michael Merickel, but being new to programming, I really can't be a hundred present sure. So in all fairness, many thanks to TJD as well, and a +1 for him as well, for being helpful and generous with his time. (as I interpret the reputation system on stack overflow, I'm perfectly within the indended purpose of +1, when using it in this manner, right ?!?)